# How to dynamically add data set to chartjs using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a sample code that shows input values in a chart using Jquery and Chartjs.

But now the chart data is 4 value, But I want to set it as a variable based on the count of an input field.

For Example; if I have 5 input field, then chart maybe show the 5 input value, or if I have 40 input value, chart show 40 value and etc.

```js
anychart.onDocumentLoad(function() {
  var dataSet = anychart.data.set([
    ["Winter", 2],
    ["Spring", 7],
    ["Summer", 6],
    ["Fall", 10]
  ]);
  var chart = anychart.column();
  // set chart title
  chart.title("chart title");
  // set data
  var column = chart.column(dataSet);
  var view = dataSet.mapAs({
    key: 0,
    value: 1
  });

  // set chart container and draw
  chart.container("container").draw();

  // update on input
  $('.example input').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).on('input', function() {
      console.log(view.get(index, 'key'), item.value)
      view.set(index, 'value', item.value)
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<table class="acf-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="6">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You mean dynamically adding and removing like this? - https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/CRUD_09

Comment: @s.kuznetsov thank you for your answer. In my case, the chart data key and value(ex: winter and its value) must be taken from the input fields, but in your case, the chart data set is predetermined.

Comment: Yes, but that was just an example.